# Scheme Racket Rackunit

Tags: testing, scheme, racket

I have to create test cases for each of my functions in Scheme. I'm getting an error: check-equal?: bad syntax
What am I doing wrong?
Here's what I have:

```
(require rackunit)

;Zip takes two lists and pairs each of the nth
;elements together
(define (zip . xss) 
  (apply map list xss)
 )

(define (zip-test2)
  (check-eq? (zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3)))
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check-equal?` and `check-eq?` both require at least 2 arguments: the expression to check and an expected value [1].  You seem to be providing only an expression to check, with no expected value.  Presumably you want something like this:

```
(check-equal? (zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
              '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)))
```

More information is available in the documentation:

[1] http://doc.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html